# SystemTap - filter own syscalls (system-wide trace)

Tags: strace, linux

I want to write simple strace-like script using SystemTap.
Main goal is to catch only some system calls (like open, close, read, write etc.) for all processes in system. (Can't do that with strace because strace'ing whole system is equal to instant system freeze).

For now it goes like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stap

probe syscall.* 
{
    printf("PID: %d\tNAME: %s\tARGSTR: %s\n",pid(), name, argstr);
}
```

The problem starts when I want to save output to file. Stap script is constantly finding itself writing to file so it's never ending loop.

I think the solution would be something like this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env stap

    probe syscall.* 
    {
        if(pid() != myOwnPid())    
        printf("PID: %d\tNAME: %s\tARGSTR: %s\n",pid(), name, argstr);
    }
```

But I don't know any function giving pid of running stap script.

Comment: Have you considered filtering on filename rather than PID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to exclude systemtap's own userspace `stapio`/`staprun` processes from the strace, use `stp_pid()`:

```
if (pid() != stp_pid())
    printf("...")
```

See also `man function::stp_pid`.

Answer (score 2):

```
perf trace -a -e open,close,read,write
```

It will filter its own calls, use `-o output` to save the output, just like with `strace`.

```
perf trace -h
```

To see how to filter some pids (xterm, X.org, ssh, etc.) and how to specify just a group of cpus, pids, mix it with tracepoints, page faults, get callchains from any event, etc.